# Python: `del my_list` vs `del[my_list]`

Tags: python

I have created a list in Python

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now if I want to delete the list, I would like to use the `del` operator like

```
>>> del my_list
```

This works fine and is probably the general way of using it. But somewhere I stumbled upon an unusual syntax

```
>>> del[my_list]
```

And this does the same thing! And now I am kind of confused how del actually works. I can understand the previous syntax with `del` being a built-in statement, but the second syntax looks like an indexing to me.

Comment: `del[my_list]` is `del [my_list]` is a target list.

Comment: This isn't indexing, this is constructing a list and then deleting it, but I believe when you construct an iterable in the delete command, it deletes everything within the iterable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`del` takes a *target list* of names, see the [reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement):

> ```
> del_stmt ::=  "del" target_list
> ```

Just like for [assignments](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) and [`for` loops](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement), a target list includes using `[...]` and `(...)` list and tuple syntax:

```
del (foo, bar)
del [spam, ham, eggs]
```

So you are not subscripting `del`, you are deleting a list of names.

You can even nest them:

```
del (foo, [ham, eggs])
```

It was simpler to re-use an existing grammar rule than to strictly limit the syntax to a comma-separated list of names.

The full grammar definition is:

> ```
> target_list     ::=  target ("," target)* [","]
> target          ::=  identifier
>                      | "(" [target_list] ")"
>                      | "[" [target_list] "]"
>                      | attributeref
>                      | subscription
>                      | slicing
>                      | "*" target
> ```

so `del *names` is technically valid too, but the compiler special-cases that last option to be a `SyntaxError` anyway:

```
>>> foo = None
>>> del *foo
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not indexing.

When `del`eting things, you can specify more than one thing to delete at a time:

```
del a, b
```

You can also surround the deletion targets with brackets or parentheses:

```
del [a, b]
del (a, b)
```

And you can do that even if there's only one deletion target:

```
del [a]
```

This behavior is mostly mirroring that of assignment, where the optional brackets or parentheses are useful for nested unpacking:

```
nested_tup = (1, (2, 3))
[a, [b, c]] = nested_tup
```

While you're technically allowed to do something like `del [a, [b, c]]`, it's equivalent to `del a, b, c`.