# del() vs del statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> li = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> li
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> del li[2] #case 1
>>> li
[1, 2, 4]
>>> del(li[2])  # case 2
>>> li
[1, 2]
>>> del (li[1]) # case 3
>>> li
[1]
>>>
```

One of my professors used case 2 to delete item from list.
As per [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#del) case 1 is right and there is also another syntactic way exist from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021822/python-del-my-list-vs-delmy-list) so case 3 also right, but as per my knowledge there is no del method exist in python, how case 2 is valid. I searched whole python documentation but could not find it.

**Update:**
if i write del method myself in my module and use case 2 at same time, how python interpreter differentiates between them or will it through an error, although i never tried until now

Comment: You can put parentheses in lots of places without affecting anything. Here they're simply redundant. Just like `return 1` is the same as `return (1)`.

Comment: okay, if i write del method in my module and use the above at same time, how python interpreter differentiates between the, although i never tried until now.

Comment: Case 2 is not a function call, it is still a statement call. The same reason why `if(cond)` and `if (cond)` and `if cond`  are all the same.

Comment: You should stick with `del (((((((((((((((((((((         list[0]                 )))))))))))))))))))))
` ;)

Comment: I never use del, I use `list.pop` also don't name your list `list`

Comment: You *can't* write a `del` function in your module. `del` is a keyword.

Comment: I use `del` (rarely) to delete slices

Comment: okay, thanks khelwood, that's why i told you i never tried.

Comment: If parenthesis are redundant in everywhere then why do i need for print() in python 3, just curious.

Comment: If you define `lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]` after each Case you will get the same result. You'r deleting the same list.

Comment: @Srinivas This is because `print` was changed from a statement (python 2) to a function (python 3).

Comment: Please do not use `list` as a variable name; you will overwrite the function by the same name and it is generally confusing.

Comment: @dawg , is `list` is not a keyword in python, then why didn't i get an error?

Comment: It is not a keyword. `list` is a function name that can be overwritten silently.

Answer (score 11):

All of them are the same, `del` is a keyword as `yield` or `return`, and `(list[1])` evaluates to `list[1]`. So `del(list[1])` and `del (list[1])` are the same. For the base case, since you dont have the `()` you need to force the extra space, hence `del list[1]`.

EDIT: You cannot redifine `del` since it is a language keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The parenthehis is not mandatory with keyword (like `if` or `del`), but can put some if you want.

it's exactly the same thing